Help with finding stationary solutions of a system of differential equations
I need help/guidance to solve the following question with the following system of equations:
$$\theta_{1}^{\prime}(t)=\omega_1+\gamma\sin[2\pi(\theta_1-\theta_2)]\\\theta_{2}^{\prime}(t)=\omega_{2}+\gamma\sin([2\pi(\theta_{2}-\theta_{1})]$$
In which $\gamma,\omega_1$ et $\omega_2$ are positive constants, and variables $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$  take values on a circle and are therefore angular variables normalized between 0 and 1.
After finding $\phi^{\prime}(t)=(\omega_1-\omega_2)+2\gamma\sin[2\pi\phi]$ by setting $\phi(t)=\theta_1(t)-\theta_2(t)$, I am asked to find the stationary solutions of this equation as well as their stability and to consider what happens when $2\gamma=|\omega_1-\omega_2|?$
The idea I have to proceed is to find the critical points such that for $f=(\omega_1-\omega_2)+2\gamma\sin[2\pi\phi]$, then $f(x*)=0$ where $(x*)$ is one of the critical points. However, given the form of the equation, I have no idea how to find the critical points, even less on how to find the stationary solutions.
For the second question, Just plugging $|\omega_1-\omega_2|$  into $f$  doesn't give me too much information a part for possibly being some sort of distance with respect of a critical point, but I'm not sure..
Can someone kindly indicate me how to properly proceed here? I'm under the impression finding the critical points it's simple but after hours being stuck I don't see how to do it. I might be also that the way I understand stability and stationary solutions might be flawed. Thanks for your time!

What's stopping you from solving $f(x^*) = 0$ directly using the $\arcsin$ function? For $2\gamma > |\omega_1 - \omega_2|$, this should yield an infinite set of pairs of critical points. I believe a saddle node bifurcation occurs at $2\gamma = |\omega_1 - \omega_2|$.

@JohnBarber So that means, $\phi = \arcsin \frac{-(\omega_1\omega_2)}{2\gamma}  $ describes all stationnary solutions right? But I do not understand why $2\gamma>|\omega_1−\omega_2|$ yields an infinite set of critical points. Could you explain a bit further please? Im a bit lost ...

Consider the function $f(\phi) = (\omega_1-\omega_2) + 2\gamma\sin(2\pi\phi)$. You want to find $\phi^$ such that $f(\phi^) = 0$. Try graphing the function $f(\phi)$ for (say) the case where $\omega_1-\omega_2 > 0$ and $2\gamma > \omega_1-\omega_2$. What does that graph look like? The critical points (fixed points) occur where the curve crosses the horizontal $\phi$ axis. Do you see how $f(\phi)$ has an infinite set of pairs of critical points? Each time the $\sin$ function "goes down" it crosses the $\phi$ axis twice, yielding a pair of such points.

I get it now! I think I can go on from here, thanks for explaining @JohnBarber !
